# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export class EstimateForm extends React.Component<IEstimateFormProps, 
IEstimateFormState> {
state: IEstimateFormState = {
cellUpdateCss: 'red',
toRow: null,
fromRow: null,
estimateList: null,
estimateItemList: [],
poseList: null,
levelList: null,
partList: null,
selectedEstimate: null,
totalEstimateItems: 0,
selectedIndexes: [],
totalEstimateAmount: 0,
grid: null,
projectId: 0,
};


constructor(props, context) {
super(props, context);
this.state.estimateList = this.props.estimateList;
}  


rowGetter = i => {
const row = this.state.estimateItemList[i];
const selectRevison = this.state.selectedEstimate.revision;
if (row['pose.poseName']) {
const poseCode = 
row['pose.poseName'].substring(row['pose.poseName'].lastIndexOf('[') + 1, 
row['pose.poseName'].lastIndexOf(']'));
for (const pose of this.state.poseList) {
if (pose.poseCode === poseCode) {
  row.pose = pose;
}
}
}

if (row['level.levelName']) {
const levelCode = row['level.levelName'].substring(
row['level.levelName'].lastIndexOf('[') + 1,
row['level.levelName'].lastIndexOf(']')
);
for (const level of this.state.levelList) {
  if (level.levelCode === levelCode) {
  row.level = level;
}
}
}

 if (row['level.part.partName']) {
 const partCode = row['level.part.partName'].substring(
 row['level.part.partName'].lastIndexOf('[') + 1,
 row['level.part.partName'].lastIndexOf(']')
 );
for (const part of this.state.partList) {
if (part.partCode === partCode) {
  row.part = part;
  }
 }
}

row.get = key => eval('row.' + key);
row.totalCost = (row.materialCost + row.laborCost) * row.amount;
const changeColor = {
  backgroundcolor: 'red'
  };
const all = document.getElementsByClassName('react-grid-Row') as 
HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
debugger; if (row.revision > selectRevison) {
 for (let i = this.state.fromRow; i <= this.state.toRow; i++) {
      all[i].style.color = 'red';   //HERE
}
return row;
}
}

handleGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
const rows = this.state.estimateItemList.slice();

for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
const rowToUpdate = rows[i];
const updatedRow = update(rowToUpdate, { $merge: updated });
rows[i] = updatedRow;
}

this.setState({ estimateItemList: rows, fromRow: (fromRow), toRow: (toRow) 
}, () => {
});

};

saveEstimateItems = () => {
if (this.state.selectedEstimate == null) {
toast.warn(<Translate 
contentKey="bpmApp.estimateForm.pleaseSelectEstimate">Please select an 
estimate</Translate>);
return;
}



render() {

return ()
}
```

I wanna to change the row color when the condition row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision . How can I prevent the change of this.color. However TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined get  error but row color is not change. how can i solve this problem it is my first project in react and i dont know where is the problemThanks for your feedback guys.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so without the rest of the context because your pasted code is difficult to read and understand, the simplest reason for your issue is in this chunk:

```
const all = document.getElementsByClassName('react-grid-Row') as 
HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
debugger; if (row.revision > selectRevison) {
 for (let i = this.state.fromRow; i <= this.state.toRow; i++) {
      all[i].style.color = 'red';   //HERE
}
```

Essentially there's multiple things that could go wrong here, but most likely there are either no rows with that class on the page, or less than your `this.state.fromRow`, I see you've got the debugger in there, but you are missing a few things:

1. You aren't doing a null check on `all` to make sure you are finding something
2. You aren't checking whether `all.length > this.state.fromRow`
3. You aren't breaking the for loop if `all.length < this.state.toRow`

It's failing because `all[i]` doesn't exist, or there's no values:

`all = [0, 1]`

and you are looking for all[3] for example

Throw in those fallbacks and check what `all` is on page load and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: It's failing because all[i] doesn't exist, or there's no values: yeap you are right but how can i solve this. i dont know

Comment: Check that you have the correct elements with the class name 'react-grid-Row' on the page... if not you have to add them, otherwise check you have enough to meet the requirements.

If this has answered your question though, please give it the tick :)